# Include file in every different level in PHP

Tags: php, include

My error page includes an image from

```
root/img/404.png
```

When user accesses wrong links like **"root/aaa"**, the image is displayed, but when the user accesses **"root/aa/aa"** the error page is displayed but the image is not loaded.

My question is: how to include a file which can be shown in every different level?

Comment: Use absolute paths in the image `src`.

Comment: Barmar means <img src="http://www.myDomainName.com/img/404.png">

Comment: @Vbudo, Barmar: that works with image, but is it safe if I include file likes "include(domainName.com/example.php)" ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, images are included using `<img>` tags, not php include() statements. But in both cases, the key is to start from the root level - e.g., for img this would be `<img src="/img/404.png">` instead of `<img src="img/404.png">` Without the leading /, the img file (or include file or whatever) is loaded relative to the current directory, which you have shown varies depending on the user's page request.